# Angular 4: How to inject directives declared in bootstrapped module(appmodule) in other modules that are imported in the appmodule?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have created a hightlight directive like the one in the angular documentation but, I am not able to use it in other modules that are imported in the appmodule.
The following is my appmodule.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PrimaryNavigationComponent } from './components/primary-navigation/primary-navigation.component';

import { DashboardModule } from 'app/features/dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { ServicesModule } from 'app/features/services/services.module';
import { NotificationsModule } from 'app/features/notifications/notifications.module';
import { AboutModule } from 'app/features/about/about.module';
import { RedirectModule } from 'app/features/redirect/redirect.module';
import { HighlightDirective } from 'app/directives/highlight/highlight.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PrimaryNavigationComponent,
    HighlightDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    DashboardModule,
    ServicesModule,
    NotificationsModule,
    AboutModule,
    RedirectModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: if you would like to use a directive inside an other directive, you need to create a shared-module that imports / exports the directive. This should be imported from the module that will be use the directive.

Answer (score 7):

The Angular module system can be confusing at first glance, but is pretty straightforward once you get used to it.

There are some simple rules to follow:

1. Every component/directive/pipe *(i.e. items you use in templates aka declarables)* must be declared in one and only one module *(not an issue for you)*
2. If you declare a component/directive/pipe called X in a module, then any other component/directive/pipe in that same module can use X in its own templates *(again not an issue for you)*
3. If you want to use a component/directive/pipe called X declared in module M in other module N, then:

   - X must be exported from module M
   - module N must import module M

And that's what you got wrong - you have to export your HighlightDirective from the module that declares it to make it available to use in other modules.

However, in your case, your AppModule already has a dependency on your feature modules *(you import your feature modules eg DashboardModule, ServicesModule etc into your AppModule)*. Angular doesn't like circular references, so you can't have your AppModule importing a feature module and then have that feature module turn around and try to import AppModule.

So the overall solution to your issue is to move the declarables (components/directives/pipes) that you want to use across multiple modules into a new module (eg SharedModule), export those declarables from that SharedModule and then have your AppModule and feature modules import that SharedModule.

Comment: thank you very much for this..BTW, I think you meant 'module N must import module M' in point 3...:)

Comment: @aashish14a, you are very right! updated the answer with the correction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the directive in module

```
@NgModule({
  ......,
  exports:[HighlightDirective]
})
export class AppModule { }
```